# Mysql values truncated in ResultSet object JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I have a mysql table like below:

```
  +-------------------------------------+----------------+
  | RANDOM_ID                           | CREATED_TIME   |
  +-------------------------------------+----------------+
  | eas133f9c49423f4e5a8ecae43ab7b4ec25 | 1391670326271  |
  | 1as19eb8dbaf5914b7f8ca38ab2a43755d9 | 1391670193759  |
  | 1as742addbf43dc402ea4b7bce81714cb7d | 1391670067688  |
  | 1as87ddab0971bf48b3985205e6aa493c42 | 1391670333973  |
  | 1asda07b7b26eb143ee85215c0153cfd7d6 | 1391710641953  |
  +-------------------------------------+----------------+
```

And, I am querying the table from Java using JDBC. I have using below query:

```
 select RANDOM_ID, group_concat('CREATED_TIME:', cast(CREATED_TIME as char)) 
 from Table_name group by RANDOM_ID
```

And I got result in ResultSet object like below:

```
  row1 --> eas133f9c49423f4e5a8ecae43ab7b4ec25, CREATED_TIME:13916
  row2 --> 1as19eb8dbaf5914b7f8ca38ab2a43755d9, CREATED_TIME:13916
  row2 --> 1as742addbf43dc402ea4b7bce81714cb7d, CREATED_TIME:13916
  row2 --> 1as87ddab0971bf48b3985205e6aa493c42, CREATED_TIME:13916
  row2 --> 1asda07b7b26eb143ee85215c0153cfd7d6, CREATED_TIME:13917
```

**The problem is the created time value truncated.**

How can I solve this problem?

**P.S:** I am using Mysql version 5.0.27

Comment: . . I always use `group_conat()` with a nested `concat()`.  I didn't realize it took multiple expressions.

Comment: why `cast(.. as char)`? Why not `varchar`?

Answer (score 0):

what about this ?

```
   group_concat('CREATED_TIME:', CREATED_TIME)
```

[**demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/428ae/2)

or use this by giving number of characters

```
 group_concat('CREATED_TIME:',cast(CREATED_TIME as char(255))
```

[**demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/428ae/4)

Comment: It returning the data as Blob in java ([B@6f7a4a80)

Comment: But the same query working fine in another JVM. Why we need to set char length?

Comment: may it set by default to 5 or something , so u need to give length of string